# htaccess redirect friendly get file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, seo, friendly-url

I know there are a lot of questions about this but i couldn't make it work.
i Have an URL like this

http://www.testo.com/admin/template/locations.php?id_location=12

and i would like to make it more friendly. I don't exactly know the SEO recommandations for these urls. I was thinkig of something like

http://www.testo.com/admin/template/locations.php/12

And the to get the $_GET variables what would i have to do?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Is `/admin/` a real directory? Does it already have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(admin/template/locations\.php)/(\d+)/?$ $1?id_location=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```